# Default Listbox Display C#

Tags: c#

Looking for a way to display a default value in a list box when launching the program e.g. the second the program is launched a default value is held and displayed in that list box until the user adds their own input?

Any ideas?

Comment: Add your default value in the form's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a collection of items in the properties window at design time or you can add via code as shown here:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Default Value");
    }
```